# stripe invalid integer NaN REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

I keep getting this error and I'm not sure why. I'm sure I'm following the documentation correctly. Have I missed something here? why can stripe not pick up the value?

https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/update.
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment

stripe session

```
    const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export default async (req, res) => {
  //
  const { items} = req.body;
  console.log(items);

  

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    line_items: [
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: 'pln',
          product_data: {
            name: items.name,
          },
          unit_amount: items.price * 100,
        },
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: "payment",

    success_url: "http://localhost:3000/Success",
    cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000/Cancel",
   
  });
  res.status(200).json({ id: session.id });
};
```

Items - this also appears in the console.

```
{
    "name": "poznan",
    "description": "hey",
    "price": 9.99
}
```

checkout session error

```
[ { name: 'poznan', description: 'hey', price: 9.99 } ]
error - Error: Invalid integer: NaN
```

stripe log

```
    parameter_invalid_integer - line_items[0][price_data][unit_amount]
    
    {
  "payment_method_types": {
    "0": "card"
  },
  "line_items": {
    "0": {
      "price_data": {
        "currency": "pln",
        "unit_amount": "NaN"
      },
      "quantity": "1"
    }
  },
```

Comment: Could it be that ` "quantity": 0` ? :)

Comment: Could you give me more information ?

Comment: That message doesn't look like an error the Stripe API would return. What is your `items` variable in this instance?

Comment: Apologies for the mistake. Data is items.

Comment: i've added more info @JonathanSteele

Answer (score 0):

I think your items variable is an array and since you're trying to access the field price on an array `items.price * 100` is evaluated as `undefined * 100` giving you the `NaN` value for `unit_amount`. You either need to access `items[0].price` instead of `items.price` or if you’re receiving multiple `items` why not map your array into `line_items` like so:

```
line_items: items.map((item)=> ({
      price_data: {
        currency: 'pln',
        product_data: {
          name: item.name,
        },
        unit_amount: item.price * 100,
      },
      quantity: 1,
    },
})),
```

Comment: this was the answer, I needed to map through it and do an implicit return.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to map through the objects and do an implicit return

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  //
  const { items} = req.body;
  console.log(items);

 const transformedItems = items.map(item => ({
   description: item.description,
   quantity: 1,
   price_data: {
     currency: 'gbp',
     unit_amount: item.price * 100,
     product_data: {
       name: item.name,

     },
   }
 }));

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: transformedItems,
    mode: "payment",
    
    success_url: "http://localhost:3000/Success",
    cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000/Cancel",
   
  });
  res.status(200).json({ id: session.id });
```